# Create a boxplot on r for a subset of values in a data frame

Tags: r, boxplot

I want to create a boxplot with just the times from where run equals 1, how do I do this?

```
Run  Time 
 1    40
 1    40
 2    50
 2    54
 3    65
```

Comment: `boxplot(myd$Time[myd$Run == 1])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
# Make example dataset
X = data.frame("Run" = sample(c(1:3), 100, replace = T), 
               "Time" = abs(rnorm(100)))

# Subset your data to only include Run 1
X2 = X[X$Run == 1, ] # could also do with "subset(X, Run == 1)"

# Make boxplot in base R
boxplot(X2$Time, main = "Boxplot of Run 1", ylab = "Time")

# Make prettier boxplot in ggplot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = X2, aes(x = "", y = Time)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  xlab("") + ggtitle("Boxplot of Run 1")
```

Comment: Should be `boxplot(X2$Time)`